# "session already exists" error with cypress session() command

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, cypress, mocha.js

Here's my use case for a cypress (v12.7.0) test in a web application:

1. Login as user student
2. Login in as user admin and perform an action that only admins have access to
3. Go back to the student user session and confirm that they are still logged in (login session is managed through a cookie).

I thought I should be able to use cy.session() to manage the sessions, but I'm struggling to get even a basic example to work as I would expect it to.

I created this very simple example that only uses cypress out-of-the-box commands:

```
describe('basic session example', () => {
  it('my test', () => {
    cy.session('foo', () => {
      cy.setCookie('foo_cookie', 'foo_value');
    });

    cy.session('bar', () => {
      cy.setCookie('bar_cookie', 'bar_value');
    });

    cy.session('foo', () => {
      cy.getCookie('foo_cookie').should((cookie) => {
        expect(cookie.value).to.equal('foo_value');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But even this basic example fails with an error on the final cy.session() call:

> This session already exists. You may not create a new session with a
> previously used identifier. If you want to create a new session with a
> different setup function, please call cy.session() with a unique
> identifier other than foo. Learn more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above implementation tries to create a unique session with id "foo" which already exists. We need to be able [to add session caching to a login helper function by wrapping the inside of the function with a call to cy.session()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Yields-Icon-namequestion-circle)

I tried with the modifications as below and able to access the cookie:

```
describe('basic session example', () => {
  it('my test', () => {
    
    accessSession("foo");

    accessSession("bar");

    accessSession("foo");
    cy.getCookie('foo_cookie').should((cookie) => {
        expect(cookie.value).to.equal('foo_value');
      });
    
  });

});

const accessSession = (name) => {
    cy.session(name, () => {
      cy.setCookie(name + "_cookie", name + "_value");
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So do both the name and the callback function reference have to be the same for cy.session() to reuse the session? And then in the case where there is a match for reusing, the callback then isn't called?

Comment: yes and yes. When cy.session is called, depending on the testIsolation parameter, the page is cleared. This will clear the existing cookies as well. So the above is the correct way to implement cy session within a test. There also workarounds like custom command implementation which can also be used

Comment: Ok, that's what was throwing me off then. I mistakenly thought the reuse conditional logic only cared about the session name such that you could pass in a different callback and it would still reuse the session. Thanks for helping me sort this out.

Comment: `accessSession ` function is not necessary, you just need to check the cookie after the `cy.session()` call, not inside it.

Comment: As per @opike's question, requires to access the foo_cookie after the "bar" session. we cannot access the cookie without the accessSession function.